# Could you clarify when "-it" should be used in a "docker run" command?

Tags: docker, docker-run

If I use

```
docker run  myimage /bin/bash -c "pwd"
```

or

```
docker run  -it myimage /bin/bash -c "pwd"
```

the results are the same. Then, what is the sense of "-it"? I learned that "-i" is for interactive, "-t" is for tty. But those are abstract nouns for me. Could you clarify when "-it" should be used in a "docker run" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/),

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process.

Essentially what that does is adding a terminal driver which allows you to interact with your container as a terminal session.

After running your container, you can run `docker ps` to get the hash id of your container which you can then access by running:

```
docker exec -it containeridhash sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-it` flag when you want interact with container.
For example:

```sh
 $ docker run -it myimage /bin/bash
```

this will give you a shell inside container and keep you connected to bash

```sh
/ #
```

And this will run any command but close the connection and drop you to your host machine's shell

```sh
 $ docker run  myimage /bin/bash -c "pwd"
```

```sh
/ 
test@host $
```

So you would use `-it` to connect and execute more commands inside container.

and finally exit out of container

```sh
/ # exit
exited
```

Comment: You can use -it flag when you don't want interact with container - Are you sure about that? When you access a container, you are interacting with it.

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean "when you don't want interact with container"?

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. Fixed now.